# How to remove square brackets from dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, dictionary

I have seen many links related to my question:

[How to remove extraneous square brackets from a nested list inside a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557014/how-to-remove-extraneous-square-brackets-from-a-nested-list-inside-a-dictionary)

[Removing square brackets from Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789135/removing-square-brackets-from-dataframe)

[Removing square brackets from Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789135/removing-square-brackets-from-dataframe)

but none of that worked

below is my example:

```
df1

column1    column2   column3    ..... upto 'n' number of columns

[data1]    data1     data1
NAN        data2     data2
[data2]    data3     [data3, data3, testing how are you guys hope you guys are doing :)]
[data3]    data3     [data4, dummy text to test to test test test] 
NAN        data4     [data5]
```

below is my tried code:

```
df1[column1] = df[column1].str[0]
# not working !
# want to give df1 instead of df1[columns] because there are lot of 
# columns
```

i want to remove only the bracket, not anything else and want to give only dataframe not along with columns because there are lot of columns !

expected output:

```
column1    column2   column3    ..... upto 'n' number of columns

data1      data1     data1
NAN        data2     data2
data2      data3     data3, data3, testing how are you guys hope you guys are doing :)
data3      data3     data4, dummy text to test to test test test
NAN        data4     data5
```

Comment: `df1['column1'].str.replace(r'[\[\]]', '')` try `str.replace`

Comment: no, i want to give df1 not df1[columns] because there are n no of columns

Comment: `df1.transform(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[\[\]]', ''))`

Comment: These are lists, and you searched for string related solutions. Regex only works on strings, not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `apply`, `explode` and `groupby`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.explode().astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(", ".join))
  column1 column2                                            column3
0   data1   data1                                              data1
1     nan   data2                                              data2
2   data2   data3  data3, data3, testing how are you guys hope yo...
3   data3   data3        data4, dummy text to test to test test test
4     nan   data4                                              data5
```

1. Use `pandas.explode()` to transform each list element to its own row, replicating index values.
2. Then `groupby` identical index values and aggregate using `str.join()`.
3. Use `apply` to apply the same function to all columns of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
       df1['column1'][i] = str(df['column1'][i]).strip('[]')
```

I didn't test this with an example dataframe, but with my experience with pandas it should work.

Edit: this tested code works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['test', '[test]']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'b']})
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
       df1['column1'][i] = str(df['column'][i]).strip('[]')
```

Comment: One shorter version that could be applied to the entire `DataFrame` is `df1.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('[]'))`.

Comment: but it throws error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' while doing df1.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('[]'))